# Add OK button to UIAlerView after it is displayed

Tags: ios, button, dynamic, uialertview

looked at this post but its not what i want.

[adding ok button at run time in UIAlertview ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857802/adding-ok-button-at-run-time-in-uialertview-ios)

i'm displaying a `UIAlertview` with no buttons where i say 'waiting for event to happen'. if that event doesn't happen or if it happens, i'd like to use same alertview to notify that event is done and click 'ok' to dismiss that alert. how do i add a button to `UIAlertview` **AFTER** it is displayed? or when the even happens should i just dismiss this one with:

```
[waitForEvent dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
waitForEvent = nil;
```

and show a new UIAlert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
UIAlertController *waitForEvent = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"waiting for event to happen" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[self presentViewController:waitForEvent animated:YES completion:nil];

// wait for five seconds
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
  [waitForEvent addAction:action];
});
```